# Implementing shorthand for data entry?

Tags: c++

For instance, if I write 32u then c++ understands it's for unsigned int or if i write 0x then c++ understands it is to be taken as a hexadecimal number.

What i want to know is if there is some way to define more of these? Like if i write 128M then it would get converted to 134217728 or 12K would be converted to 12288 etc.

Comment: Are you talking about in the program itself, or user-input to the program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use C++11 user-defined literals:

```
constexpr unsigned long long operator"" _M(unsigned long long lit) {
    return lit * 1024 * 1024;
}

//use: 128_M
```

The underscore is there because all user-defined literals defined by you need to begin with one. The ones that do not are reserved and will start to be used by the standard come C++14.

Comment: great, thanks. unfortunately i have to work on vs10 so i guess ill just keep using free functions

Comment: @KarliRaudsepp, Yes, I don't know of anything that great in C++03. It always helps to have knowledge of some C++11 features if you have that luxury later :)